# Using latex and variables in Python (title Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to use both variables and latex notation in Python(3.6) for my title in Matplotlib.

But it seems to confuse what is between the {} for latex notation vs for the variable in Python when I used my default method:

```
plt.title(r'E_obs and E_syn @ t={0}, $Q_i^{-1}$={1}, $\ell$={2}'.format(time, q_intr, lpath))
```

It does not run because it seems to be confused about the {-1}, trying to read is as an index for the variables stated in .format().
The error is:

```
KeyError: '-1'
```

What I tried after some research is:

```
plt.title(f'E_obs and E_syn @ t={time}, $Q_i^{-1}$={q_intr}, $\ell$={lpath}')
```

It runs but my -1 that should be at the top of my Q_i is just a - and the 1 is at the same level as the Q.

Anyone any suggestions?

p.s. I am new to this forum for asking questions myself; any tips on this are welcome as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some brackets shouldn't be considered by `format`, then you should double them (e.g. `{{-1}}`).

See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatstrings :

> f you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}.

In your case, I would expect the following to work:

```
r'E_obs and E_syn @ t={0}, $Q_i^{{-1}}$={1}, $\ell$={2}'.format(time, q_intr, lpath)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I have looked at the duplicate question (also before asking my question) but I did not understand that answer. Yours I do, thanks